# error: constructor Thread in class Thread cannot be applied to given types;

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

Hey I have this very weird bug that is probably related to my java version.

Here's my class:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;


public class ClientThread extends Thread{
    private Socket clientSocket;

    ClientThread(Socket clientSocket) {
        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

            String message;
            while (((message = in.readLine()) != null)) {
                // out.println(message);
                System.out.println(message);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
    }

    public Socket getClientSocket() {
        return clientSocket;
    }

    public void setClientSocket(final Socket clientSocket) {
        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
    }
}
```

Here's my java version:

```
java version "1.7.0_72"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_72-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.72-b04, mixed mode)
```

When I compile the class I get the following error:

```
ClientThread.java:11: error: constructor Thread in class Thread cannot be applied to given types;
    ClientThread(Socket clientSocket) {
                                      ^
  required: Socket
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error
```

This error is very weird and I don't understand it. I found pretty much the exact same class on tutorial on the internet. I'm guessing that I have wrong version of java or something. My OS is ubuntu.

Comment: Odd - it compiles for me...

Comment: Do you have your own `Thread` class that you're extending, that has a constructor that takes a `Socket`?  That is the only way you get a compiler error here.

Comment: @JonSkeet that's what I guessed. It probably has something to do with java versions. Any ideas how to debug what's wrong ?

Comment: @Marijus: Are you sure you don't have another `Thread` class somewhere? Try extending `java.lang.Thread` explicitly...

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem. I don't have another Thread class however there wasn't an import in my code. I don't know what Thread class it was extending. I added import java.lang.Thread and it worked. Thank you guys!

Comment: You should not ever have to import anything from the java.lang package. Otherwise your code would be importing java.lang.String, etc. You have a Thread.java or Thread.class in the same package as ClientThread.java sitting in your class path somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you had a `Thread` class in the default package - potentially just the class file, rather than the source file. `java.lang.*` is imported automatically, and all the rest of your imports are single-class imports, so that's the only thing I can see that could have been going on.

You should look at the directory where you're compiling, and make sure that it *only* has the classes you expect it to... if you're rebuilding, you could just delete all the class files first, and then you know that only the source files are going to be relevant.

While you *could* keep extending `java.lang.Thread` explicitly, it would be much better to find the rogue `Thread` class and delete it.